# C variable assignment and R equivalent

Tags: c, r, variables, variable-assignment

Hi I am trying to understand the following variable assignment in C, and try re-write it in R.  I use R often but have only really glanced at C.

```
    int age,int b_AF,int b_ra,int b_renal,int b_treatedhyp,int b_type2,double bmi,int ethrisk,int fh_cvd,double rati,double sbp,int smoke_cat,int surv,double town
    )
    {
        double survivor[3] = {
            0,
            0.996994316577911,
            0.993941843509674

        };
    a = /*pre assigned*/ 
    double score = 100.0 * (1 - pow(survivor[surv], exp(a)) );
    return(score);
}
```

how does survivor[surv] work in this context? An explanation would be helpful, and any input on how to do the assignment in R would be a bonus.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an aggregate initializer:

```
double survivor[3] = {
    0,
    0.996994316577911,
    0.993941843509674
};
```

and is equivalent to:

```
double survivor[3];
survivor[0] = 0;
survivor[1] = 0.996994316577911;
survivor[2] = 0.993941843509674;
```

and `survivor[surv]` is the value stored at index of the `survivor` array. Array indexes run from `0` to `N - 1` so if `surv` was `1` then `survivor[surv]` has value of `0.996994316577911`.

---

Note, the function as currently written does not check that `surv` is a valid index for the array `survivor` (i.e. `surv > -1` and `surv < 3`) and runs the risk of undefined behaviour.

Comment: thanks very much - I thought it has something to do with assigning variable into an array.

Answer (score 3):

Given the Answer of @hmjd then, the R equivalent would be

```
survivor <- c(0, 0.996994316577911, 0.993941843509674)
```

or if `survivor` already exists and you wish to assign into the first 3 elements:

```
survivor[1:3] <- c(0, 0.996994316577911, 0.993941843509674)
```

(Note R's indices are 1-based unlike C's 0-based ones.)

---

As for the extraction, the general idea is the same as with C, but the details matter:

```
R> survivor[0] ## 0 index returns an empty vector
numeric(0)
R> survivor[-1] ## negative index **drops** that element
[1] 0.9969943 0.9939418
R> survivor[10] ## positive outside length of vector returns NA
[1] NA
R> surv <- 2
R> survivor[surv] ## same holds for whatever surv contains
[1] 0.9969943
```

Comment: excellent - thanks very much - and regarding calling survivor[surv] within the pow function, does that simply stay the same?

Comment: Yes, `survivor[surv]` will extract the `surv`th index of the `survivor` vector, though how indices outside the range are handled will be different to C. I'll update the Answer.

Comment: Thanks Gavin - that's very helpful and I will certainly be writing some error handlers for each case you have presented.